# Is it possible to replace Spring @Scope("request") with JSR-330 @Scope variant?

Tags: java, spring, jsr330

Or, can I bound a custom implementation of `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.Scope` interface with a specific `@Scope`-annotated annotation?

For example, I have customized a new scope type:

```
@javax.inject.Scope @Retention(RUNTIME)
@interface Conversation {}

class ConversationScope implements Scope { ... }

class ConversationScopeConfigurer extends BeanFactoryPostProcessor
    { beanFactory.registerScope("conversation", new ConversationScope()); }
```

Now I want to use it as,

```
@Component
@Conversation
class Topic { ... }
```

instead of,

```
@Component
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope("conversation")
class Topic { ... }
```

Is it possible?

Is there something like "AnnotationPostProcessor" in spring-context?

Comment: If it doesn't work out of the box with `<context:annotation-driven/>` or `<context:component-scan/>`, then it likely won't work at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems to be possible by registering a [custom scope resolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Jsr330ScopeMetadataResolver.html) with your `<context:component-scan>`

For example:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.company" scope-resolver="org.springframework.context.annotation.Jsr330ScopeMetadataResolver" />
```

See also this example of a [bridge for JSR-299 annotations](https://github.com/matzew/spring-cdi-bridge) if you need to customize your solution a little bit more.